# Rails: redirect to previous page after login doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I am trying to redirect to the page from where I clicked login, but after logining in it doesn't redierect to previous page but stays on login page (although the user is already logged in).
Here is my code:

session_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
end


def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
end

def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
end
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include SessionsHelper
  def new
  end
  def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:session][:username])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])   
      cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
      #redirect_to root_url,:notice => "Logged in!"
        redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  def destroy
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    #session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

I also tried to write in create function in sessions_controller.rb

> redirect_to request.referer

but it doesn't work.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try `redirect_to :back`?

Comment: This will work for sure

Comment: yes. it's doing the same. just staying on login page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens at `store_location`.

Though you havn't said in question, I guess you probably put this method in `before_filter`. So, no matter GET or POST or other request, the request hit this filter at first and store location.

Now, in this case, actually the user has two requests. One is to `#new` by GET, and the other is to `#create` by POST. In the later, his last request to `#new` was recorded as the going back location. So you'll see you always go back to `#new` :)

The solution is to filter the location to be stored.

```
def store_location
  disable_pattern = /\A\/user*/
  session[:return_to] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath ~= disable_pattern
end
```

This pattern could solve current problem but not exclusive. In practice you may see even JS/JSON requests has been recorded, so you may need to add more restrictions according to the specific case. For example, only apply `before_filter` on #show or #index, use white list, etc.

Comment: Thanks for explenation. I tried like that, now it's redirecting me to 'root_url/sessions'

Comment: I don't understand what is `root_url/sessions` Do you have such path?

Comment: where do I write my `before_filter: store_location` ? I put it now in application_controller and also the `def store_location` and `def redirect_back_or(default)` in application_controller. is that correct?

Comment: I don't know how `'sessions'` appeared from question code. Seems impossible. Two things to note in `redirect_to_or`: 1. `session.delete(:return_to)` is unnecessary and will make your return path blank. 2. You should add `root_url` after `default` as the final fallback, what if `default` is invalid as well? For the location, yes, ApplicationController is the way to go.

Comment: For my login form I have the following code : '<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :username,:placeholder=>'username' %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder=>'password'  %><br>
      <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn-login" %>
    <% end %>'

and then I get '<form method="post" action="/sessions" accept-charset="UTF-8">'

how can I change my code for _form ?

Answer (score 0):

I think `request.referer` may not have worked because of a typo in the method. It should be `request.referrer`.